# Connect database from applet

Tags: java, applet, database-connection

Is it possible to connect database from applet???

Answer (score 5):

The sandbox requires that an applet connect back to the server and port it came from.  If your database connection port is different from the servlet engine, it's not possible.

Best to put a servlet in between the applet and database.  That way your database isn't exposed directly on the network.  It gives the servlet a change to check authorization, bind variables, etc.

Comment: +1 Good idea to mention the reasons such as authorization etc.